# Is it possible to override radio buttons style with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I need to make special radio buttons, is it possible to make my own images to cover default style of radio buttons? If it is not possible what is best way to do this with jQuery or is there good plugin for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I would also recommend using jQuery, a very nice plugin is the [jqTransform plugin](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/). Check out this video tutorial by Chris Coyier in which he uses the plugin from scratch in [one of his css-tricks screen casts](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/62-advanced-form-styling-functionality/).

Answer (score 3):

you can control every aspect of the radio via CSS, using images or basic styling, like padding, color, backgorund, etc.
That said, I also recommend you use a framework, like [jQuery Checkbox.](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/).

Alternatively, look at [this blog entry](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-skin-html-form-elements-in.html) for further suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Some basic changes can be made via CSS, to the size etc, but they are fairly unreliably reproduced across different browsers (surprise, surprise).

Outside of CSS, I've had good results with [jQuery Checkbox](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/).